# Unable to Update hardware support software

Tags: 12.04

Here is the error text I get when clicking install:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty: Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1 is to be installed
                            Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                            Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is to be installed
xserver-xorg-lts-trusty: Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty (>= 2:1.11) but 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2~precise1 is to be installed
```

Comment: is this really a duplicate of the question posed above? the question may contain "unmet dependencies", but the reality is that this is due to a bug in the upgrade for the hardware stack for the LTS release. the so called duplicate refers to a plethora of ways to muck around with the package manager, which might be all fine and dandy for somebody trying to install an "old" version of their favourite software. but is it really safe to send them off, mucking around with system dependencies referred to in a hardware support stack upgrade, or distro release?

Comment: Command:

amd64:
apt-get install -V libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty:i386 libgles2-mesa-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-trusty

Comment: Command: i386:
apt-get install -V libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-trusty xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-trusty libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-trusty x11-xserver-utils-lts-trusty mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-trusty libgles2-mesa-lts-trusty libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty

Comment: @RapidWebs You are right, this is not really a duplicate, but the problem is caused by a bug in Ubuntu, so if the question were reopened it would just get immediately closed again as "Bug report"

Answer (score 2):

No solution as of yet, but this bug discusses the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1328264

Comment: following a comment in the bug report you have referred to, i was able to install the necessary dependencies, thus allowing me to finish the installation of the hardware support stack. in my opinion, this should not have been marked as a duplicate, as the question which was referred to did not really answer *this* question. this question could have been answered in a way which explains what the issue is, and how to explicitly resolve it. that would have helped alot of people whom are having this very same situation. i took the liberty of posting a comment above on how to get it working. thanks